# Is there a way to add up the elements within a bag in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am pretty new at Java, so please bear with me.

So I have a class with a generic  for both the bag class and interface class as I have to have two bags: one that contains strings, and another that contains doubles (it could also be floats as an alternate, if that would work better with the program). How would I go about writing in the bag class and interface a way to add up the second bag with doubles or floats in it in order to get a total value that the bag holds?

Comment: It would be good if you could post your Bag class.  If it's backed by an array, you could sum it up like this: `double[] a = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }; double sum = Arrays.stream(a).sum();`

Comment: Welcome to SO! "Bag" is an abstract data type, there is no such data structure primitive. Loop over the data structure primitive you're using to implement the bag (probably an array or linked list) and add each element to an accumulator variable. Without a code attempt as a [mcve], I'm not sure I can offer much more than this advice.

Answer (score 1):

If your Bag class can hold things that aren't numbers, then giving it a method to add its contents together isn't appropriate.

Let's say your Bag interface looks like:

```
interface Bag<T> {
   void add(T item);
   Iterator<T> items();
}
```

If we want to add a method to sum the contents of a bag of Doubles it would look like:

```
interface Bag<T> {
   ...
   double sum();
   ...
}
```

How could we implement that?

```
class BagImpl<T> implements Bag<T> {
   private List<T> contents; // or however we store the members internally
   
   double sum() {
      double total = 0.0;
      for (T t: contents) {
        total = total + ??? // how do we turn T into a number?
      }
      return total;
   }
```

There is no general way to treat an instance of `Object` as a number, and we don't know anything about `T` other than that it is a subclass of `Object`.

But the concept of being able to apply some function which combines elements of our Bag into a single value is a useful one.

You could give the `Bag` interface a method to 'reduce' its contents to a single value:

```
interface Bag<T> {
   ...
   T reduce(T initial, BiFunction<T,T> f);
   ...
}
```

so summing over the Bag would be done:

```
double t = bag.reduce(0.0, (a,b) -> a + b);
```

And the implementation of `reduce` would be something like:

```
public T reduce(T initial, BiFunction<T,T> f) {
   T finalValue = initial;
   for (T t : contents) {
      finalValue = f.apply(finalValue, t);
   }
   return finalValue;
}
```

Comment: For someone pretty new to java a bit more explanation would be in order. ;)

Comment: @JoopEggen hopefully that's clearer now.